# Eclipse is not including my javascript file when exporting as a war

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, export, war

How do you include javascript files when exporting as a WAR?

Comment: Is it in the WebContent directory, but not in the WEB-INF directory?

Comment: Give as a screenshot of your project structure.

Comment: I have put it in WebContent but not Web-Inf, but it still seems not to be getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it somewhere in the WebContent folder (not in the WEB-INF) folder.

If you curious you can view the structure of a war by renaming it to zip.

Comment: Hi guys (this is me, but on a different computer as my other one isn't connecting to the internet right now, thus the different account.) I put it in the WebContent folder, which is where all the other html and jsp files are, but my javascript form validations are not working. I'm not sure why this is. Also, on an unrelated note my tomcat server seems to be broken unless I run it through eclipse: the ODBC doesn't work, at least, unless through eclipse. I think Eclipse made some changes but I don't know how to change back.

Comment: So, my project is functionally the same in that the javascript is not working or not found for some reason. I'm not running it as a war but just as a project from eclipse since my tomcat is behaving so strangely.

Comment: After several tries, I've confirmed that my javascript won't work through eclipse and my odbc won't work when run in browser instead of eclipse. This didn't happen before and is highly worrisome...

Comment: Okay, now the javascript is working. I didn't change anything at all. I don't know what happened but I'm glad it's working.